# RemoteServerException always throws 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: c#, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to use `RemoteServerException` in my code like this:

```
throw new RemoteServerException(response.StatusCode,response.IsSuccessStatusCode,newUri("http://localhost:5045/myapi"),null,content);
```

but it always throws `500` instead of **`response.StatusCode`** that I set. why?

Answer (score 1):

because it shows remote api's response in it's body like this image:[image]